# How post input value of an element by name with jQuery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to post the forms with post method in jquery, what is the correct syntax?

The modules a, b, c are multiple.
I have to send everything via post and receive the response via alert.

This is my code:

```
<input type="text" name="type">
<input type="text" name="model">

<input type="text" name="a[]">
<input type="text" name="b[]">
<input type="text" name="c[]">
<input type="text" name="a[]">
<input type="text" name="b[]">
<input type="text" name="c[]">


$('#start').click(function(){

var type = $('input[name=type]').val()
var model = $('input[name=model]').val()

var a = [];
$('input[name="a[]"]').each(function() {
    a.push($(this).val());
});

var b = [];
$('input[name="b[]"]').each(function() {
    b.push($(this).val());
});

var c = [];
$('input[name="c[]"]').each(function() {
    c.push($(this).val());
});

var send = .....({
    type:type:,model:model,a:a,b:b,c:c
});

$.ajax({
    url: '.post.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {send:send},
    success: function(data) {
    //alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Note you should remove the last `:` in `type:type:`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var send = function() {
  return {
    type:type,
    model:model,
    a:a,
    b:b,
    c:c
  };
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'post.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {send:send()},
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
});
```